# How to display multiple Lookup column values on one line whilst retaining the links

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

By default, the values in a Lookup column display as links.

Clicking on these links takes you to the relevant item in the lookup list.

When setting the column to `Allow multiple values`, each value is displayed on a separate line.

[image]

To make the values appear on one line, I have applied this column formatting:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=join(@currentField.lookupValue, ', ')"
}
```

This results in the desired behavior of the values being on one line, separated by commas, eg:

```
Value1, Value2, Value3
```

However, the values are just plain text, ie the links have been removed.

How can I retain the links for each of the values, whilst still displaying them on one line.

**Edit 1:**

It seems that Lookup columns have two properties available via column formatting:

- `.lookupValue`
- `.lookupId`

When you click on a link in a Lookup column, it goes to a URL with this structure:

```
https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/Lists/Some%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID=n
```

Where the `n` at the end of the URL is the `lookupId`.

So one possible solution would be to:

- use `.lookupId` to get the ID of the item in the lookup list
- for each value in the lookup column, construct the URL and concatenate the `.lookupId` value to the end

Using [this post an inspiration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/292626), the following code almost works, but the ID value in each of the links is output as the same (and is also incorrect):

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "width": "100%"
      },
      "txtContent": "=join(@currentField.lookupValue, ', ')",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/Lists/Some%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + [$ID]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Based on [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/281341), which references [this blog post](https://thechriskent.com/2019/04/04/generate-list-formatting-elements-in-a-loop-using-foreach/), the following achieves the desired behaviour using `forEach`, but it adds a trailing comma on the end of all last values in the column:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "lookupIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "=[$lookupIterator.lookupValue] + ',  '",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/Lists/Some%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + [$lookupIterator.lookupId]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is another way to do it using `operator` and `operands` but it still shows the undesired trailing comma:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "lookupIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
            "[$lookupIterator.lookupValue]", ", "
          ]
      },
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/Lists/Some%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + [$lookupIterator.lookupId]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to somehow define different concatenation on the last item in the loop, with something like:

```
"=if(loopIndex('lookupIterator') == length(@currentField - 1), 'DON'T ADD COMMA', 'DO ADD COMMA')"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "lookupIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "=if(loopIndex('lookupIterator') == length(@currentField) - 1, [$lookupIterator.lookupValue], [$lookupIterator.lookupValue] + ',  ')",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/Lists/Some%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + [$lookupIterator.lookupId]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It uses `forEach`, an `if()` statement, `loopIndex` and `length()` to concatenate values conditionally, i.e:

- if it's the last item in the loop, don't add the separating comma
- if it's not the last item in the loop, do add the separating comma

To be honest, i'm surprised the conditional structure worked in there, and the referenced column values as well.

**Bonus**

It seems you can also add a `style` property under `txtContent` which uses the same conditional logic, just to make the gap between values larger than the default 1 space character, i.e:

```
"style": {
  "padding-right": "=if(loopIndex('lookupIterator') == length(@currentField) - 1, '0px', '5px'"
},
```